# Regular Expression Python Trace back

Tags: python, regex

I have a string something like this:

```
opt/custom/building/BuildingInput/address/BuildingUnderwritingInput/Name
```

I need to catch all the words having 'Input' and delete them from the path.
So my final string will be:

```
opt/custom/building/address/Name
```

I tried something like this but it didnt work

```
x = "opt/custom/building/BuildingInput/address/BuildingUnderwritingInput/Name"
re.sub(r'Input/', r'/' , x.rstrip())
```

And it gave me

```
opt/custom/building/Building/address/BuildingUnderwriting/Name
```

The "Building" of "BuildingInput" and "BuildingUnderwriting" of "BuildingUnderwritingInput" are retained here. I want the whole word 'BuildingInput" and "BuildingUnderwritingInput" to be omitted. Any help? Or if anyone can tell me how I can backtrace from occurrence of "Input" to the first occurrence of "/" so that I can match the whole word "BuildingInput" and "BuildingUnderwritingInput"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex to remove all words ending with Input within slashes (/):

```
(/)[^/]+Input(?=/)
```

For your case:

```
x = "opt/custom/building/BuildingInput/address/BuildingUnderwritingInput/Name"
re.sub(r'(/)[^/]+Input(?=/)', r'' , x.rstrip())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. It worked! Can you tell me what (/) and (?=/) did?

Comment: Sure. (/) just represents a / at the beginning. (?=) is a positive lookahead operator which ensures that (/) is present ahead of Input but isn't considered in the regex match. So essentially we look for a word ending with Input and slash(/) but don't include the slash (/) in the regex so that it isn't deleted. You can read up more about lookarounds [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

Comment: No problem :) If this answer helped solve your problem, you might want to mark it as accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are only searching and replacing `Input/`, you have to search for the whole word, for example by using this regex:

```
re.sub(r'/\w*Input/', r'/' , x.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove 0 or more chars that are not a slash (`[^/]*`) till after the point that `Input` followed by a slash appears:

```
import re
x = "opt/custom/building/BuildingInput/address/BuildingUnderwritingInput/Name"
print(re.sub(r'[^/]*Input/', r'' , x.rstrip()))
```

If it is possible that the last element of the path also contains an `Input` word (without a trailing slash) you can use this instead:

```
x = "address/BuildingUnderwritingInput"
print(re.sub(r'[^/]*Input(/|$)', r'' , x.rstrip()))
```

Here either `/` or the end of the string (`$`) match after `Input`. However this leaves one slash if the last word is matched. If this is a problem you can remove it seperately:

```
x = "address/BuildingUnderwritingInput"
x = re.sub(r'[^/]*Input(/|$)', r'' , x.rstrip())
print(re.sub(r'/$', r'' , x))
```